# Setting Android Textcolor being ignored for 5.0 but works for 6.0

Tags: android, textcolor

Set the Android app theme as Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar, but when I do

```
    android:textColor="@color/black"
```

for a TextView in the xml layout, the color won't change.

However, everything works fine for Android 6.0 devices, but it's not working for Android 5.0 or 4.0.3.

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
```

Setting background color works fine. It's just the text color of different views.

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
```

Comment: Which support library version do you use?

Comment: Edited to answer your question.

Comment: check my answer, it's your solution. Set your version manually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using version **v24.0.0 alpha1** or **+**, turn back to **v23.2.1**. There is a bug about setting text color on buttons, textviews etc.

Use:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
```

Comment: same things applies for the com.android.support:design library. It seems that the v24.0.0 alpha1 wasn't a good release at all..