# android:textColor= doesn't change the color

Tags: android, textcolor

I'm new on android. After spending 3 days on this I can't figure this out. `android:textColor=` on a textview but it doesn't change the color. All the other values I can change, but not the textColor.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide a [mcve] demonstrating your problem.

Comment: sorry i dont know much about android yet so i dont know what is important to mention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check my answer at similar question. 
[Setting Android Textcolor being ignored for 5.0 but works for 6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36361717/setting-android-textcolor-being-ignored-for-5-0-but-works-for-6-0/36361912#36361912)

Change your support library version to **23.2.1** do not use **+**
It uses 24.0.0 alpha1 version which is buggy.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
```

Comment: thenks, that solves all may thexcolors problems now i must to clean all may tests and patches o try to set the color, thanks again