# Why is android:textColor being ignored in 5.0 but working in 6.0?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-appcompat

I do know it's pretty much the exact same question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36361717/setting-android-textcolor-being-ignored-for-5-0-but-works-for-6-0), however the accepted answer there doesn't seem to work for me and I am not sure why.

Here is my build.gradle relevant bits:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.company.project"
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
}
```

As I reckon it might be a theme-related issue, so here is the theme used in my activities:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Update your support repository to the latest. Try with the latest version

Comment: probably bug in support library, it does not work in 24.0.+ in alpha version